# Select * in Postgres not selecting duplicates; how to get duplicates?

Tags: sql, postgresql

when I run this query:

```
SELECT item_id 
FROM cart
WHERE user_id = 6
```

I get: 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 2 2

---when I run:

```
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE id IN(
  SELECT item_id FROM cart
  WHERE user_id = 6
```

I get:

```
1  Apple   0.40   red fruit
2  Banana  0.30   yellow
3  Mango   1      yellow fruit
4  Carrot  0.50   orange vegetable
```

I'd like to get it where it sends the duplicates too for how many times it is there. I had the same problem with SUM where it only add the values once but not for any duplicates. How is there a way to get the duplicates to be returned also? and hopefully with SUM too

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a join:

```
SELECT itm.* 
FROM items itm 
  JOIN cart crt on crt.item_id = itm.id
WHERE crt.user_id = 6;
```

Comment: Awesome that worked! I went over joins when I 1st learn SQL and remember that shorthand table name. Ill have to back and refresh myself on JOINS! Thank You, I appreciate it!